# QT ButtonBox translation (static)

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I need to translate standard buttons from ButtonBox into russian. When i use dynamic library, i've loaded QTranslator this way

```
QTranslator qtTranslator;
if(qtTranslator.load("qt_ru",QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)))
    qDebug() << "translation loaded";
qDebug()<<QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath);
a.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
```

TranslationPath was "C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\translations". I've linked my project statically and don't know how to translate Buttonbox/ I've tried add "qt_ru.qm" file from old TranslationPath to project directory, but translator don't load this file. New value of QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath is "C:/Qt/5.2.1/Src/qtbase/translations", but there is no such directory.

Comment: Are you sure `QLocale::system().name()` is just "ru"? Why do you hard code it? Is "translation loaded" printed?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Locale is not important now. Earlier translation was successfully loading and "loaded" printed. Now, if i try to load .qm file from project directory оr from new TranslationPath, this doesn't happen.

Comment: What do you mean by new translation path?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I've statically linked library (i think that i did it. Actions that i made [here](http://goo.gl/hnlQfO)(of course with my directories and also i've added ODBC to configure.exe properties). After that value of QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath is "C:/Qt/5.2.1/Src/qtbase/translations", but there is no such directory.©